# Android does not receive UDP Broadcast

Tags: java, android, c++, linux

I have a server written in C++ that will send UDP Broadcasts over the network with this code (ive reduced the code to the minimum needed, so there might be one or two syntax errors here):

```
bool open_socket()
{
    sockfd_ = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);
    if (sockfd_ == -1)
    {
        logger_.error("Error creating socket (%d).", errno);
        return false;
    }

    int bc = broadcast ? 1 : 0;
    if (::setsockopt(sockfd_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (void *)&bc, sizeof(bc)) < 0)
    {
        logger_.error("Could not set broadcast option.");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        is_broadcast_ = broadcast;
    }
    return true;
}

int write_to_socket(const std::string &address, uint16_t port, uint8_t *buffer, int bufsize)
{
    struct hostent *h = ::gethostbyname(address.c_str());
    if (!h)
    {
        logger_.error("Could not resolve %s", address.c_str());
        return 0;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in remote_server;
    ::memset(&remote_server, 0, sizeof(remote_server));
    remote_server.sin_family = h->h_addrtype;
    remote_server.sin_port = htons(port);
    ::memcpy ( (char *) &remote_server.sin_addr.s_addr, h->h_addr_list[0], h->h_length);
    int res = ::sendto(sockfd_, buffer, bufsize, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_server, sizeof(remote_server));
    if (res == -1)
    {
        logger_.error("Could not send to \"%s\" (%d)", address.c_str(), errno);
    }
    return res;
}
```

I use the code with:

```
socket_.write("192.168.42.255", 18997, (uint8_t *)magic_packet_.c_str(), magic_packet_.size() + 1);
```

with `magic_packet_` beeing a `std::string` with the value `SPCCBC`;

When using this code I can see the package appear in wireshark correctly. Also other C++ programs receive the broadcast, so I assume the code is working.

Now I have an Android app that will receive the said broadcast packet. The Thing is that the package will not show up and the `receive` function will block infinit. Here is the code (note that this is executed on another thread than the mainthread!):

```
package net.dev_shack.silentplayerpartyclient;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class UdpBroadcastListener extends Thread
{
    private DatagramSocket socket;

    AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized (this)
        {
            try {
                socket = new DatagramSocket(18997);//, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
            }
            catch (SocketException e) {
                Log.e("UdpBroadcastListener", "Could not create DatagramListenSocket");
                notify();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            /*catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                notify();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }*/
            running.set(true);
            notify();
        }

        while (running.get())
        {
            byte[] message = new byte[1500];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
            try {
                socket.receive(packet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                continue;
            }

            Log.i("UdpBroadcastReceiver", "Got: " + packet.toString());
        }
    }

    public void stop_listener() {
        running.set(false);
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The Android device is in the same network and has an IP in the range (the device has `192.168.42.116`, the sender has `192.168.42.5` and the network is `192.168.42.0` with netmask `255.255.255.0`).

Is there something wrong with the java code? Note the commented `InetAddress`, I have tried it with and without.

Comment: Don't see any problems. The Android 
device isn't dozing, is it?

Comment: It is set to be always on when ADB attached. The app is in the foreground and never minimized, etc.